# Why is g++ refusing to create uic3.exe?

Tags: qt, permissions, g++

I have MSYS installed and I am trying to compile Qt 4.8.0 as a set of static libraries on Windows 8. I've got the libraries built and unfortunately when building the Qt tools, I get this error:

```
$ g++ -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o ../../../bin/uic3.exe object_s
cript.uic3.Release  -L'd:/qt/lib' -L'd:/qt/lib' -lQt3Support -lQtSql -lQtXml -l
QtGui -lQtNetwork -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -loleaut32 -limm32 -lwinmm -lwinspool -lms
img32 -lQtCore -lole32 -luuid -lws2_32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32
 -lssleay32 -llibeay32

d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link
 failed: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

For some strange reason, I'm getting a weird error about permissions - but I've double-checked that `g++` has write access to the folder in question. I've tried creating the file `uic3.exe` in the output folder and sure enough, `g++` deletes it and tries to create the file but fails again.

So I tried running MSYS under an administrator account - still it refused to compile. There is plenty of disk space, so I doubt any sort of disk problem is to blame. I tried running `g++` with the `-v` option to get some more details, but there was no further information provided.

What could cause this error?

---

**Edit:** I've tried writing the output file to different locations (by modifying the `-o` parameter) and it still reports the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Anti-virus software could cause this, including *Microsoft Security Essentials*. Disable them!

And, make sure you open MSYS console with administrator priviledges.

Comment: I tried running MSYS with administrator privileges and the only anti-virus software I have installed is Windows Defender.